# Consider Z5 and Z20 as ring modulo 5 and 20 respectively..Then number of homomorphism φ:Z5 to Z20

Tags: group-theory

Consider $Z_5$ and $Z_{20}$ as ring modulo 5 and 20 respectively..Then number of homomorphism $φ:Z_5 \to Z_{20}$ is a)1 b)2 c)4 d)5
since $Z_5$ and $Z_{20}$ is also group then number of group homomorphism is g.c.d of $(5,20)=5$
again if we consider ring homomorphism then number of ring homomorphism is 2.so in this case which option I will chose.I am totally confused.

Comment: Ring homomorphisms usually send 1 to 1. If that is the case for you, then there is at most one ring homomorphism.

Comment: I think it is trivial ring homomorphism

Comment: the number of ring homomorphsm from Zm to Zn  is 2^{W(n)-W(g.c.d of (m,n))}.where w(n) is number of prime divisor of n.so there are 2 ring homomorphism ,1 ois trivial and other is non-trivial ring homomorphism

Comment: $Bbb Z_5$ has no proper ideals so the homomorphism is either injective or trivial. If $1$ is mapped to $1$ then what happens to $1+1+1+1+1$?